# iPad split view

Tags: ipad

I have a split view and on the left side of it I have a table view now I want whenever I click a cell on the table a new view is loaded on the left side itself. How can i do it any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but check out Apple's sample code - [MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html).